# How do I replace an ISO while installing Linux as a VMWare guest?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-workstation

Here is a situation I am in an environment where torrents are blocked.
I have to create a Cent OS VM 64 bit version of Cent OS.
Which comes on 7 CD ISO images

http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/5/isos/x86_64/

I have downloaded 7 CD ISO's
http://mirror-fpt-telecom.fpt.net/centos/5.5/isos/x86_64/

I do not (can not ) use torrents.
Cent OS 5.5 64 bit version DVD ISO is not available from any of their mirrors.

So when I started installing CentOS as guest the installer asked me to enter 2nd CD I tried to pause the VM and change the CD location it did not happened.

Those options were greyed out.
Powering off the VM also was of no use.

Is there a way I can change the CD from CD 1 to CD 2 when the installer asks me to do while creating the guest.

I find it really bizarre that this is not possible because if I were to do it on an actual machine I can always change the CD here I don't see any such method.
I do not have 8 CD to burn to.
Any suggestions in this situation.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to pause the VM, just disconnect the CD drive, change to a different .ISO and reconnect - it's as simple as that.

Comment: It is the ISO on the hard disk not a CD which is having image.

Comment: I don't understand...the ISO is the image. Why can't you point the drive to the ISO image of disc 2?

Comment: @Bond: Right. What he describes in his answer is the "virtual" way of "ejecting" a CD and "inserting" a new one. I would expect all of the ISOS to be in a folder on the host computer.

Comment: @Bond - perhaps you and this question would be better suited to our colleagues on our sister site superuser.com - I'll move this along to them.

Comment: @Bond, he's talking about the Virtual CD device within VMware, NOT your physical CD drive.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just hook up 7 CD drives to the VM.

Comment: You cant' change the Virtual CD while the VM is paused.  It needs to be running in order to process the Eject/Insert virtual drive actions.  This is why the option is grayed out when you pause.  Just leave it running and change the ISO that the virtual drive points to.

Answer (score 2):

```
   1. While your virtual machine is running (not suspended or paused), click "VM" which is located along the top of the Workstation GUI by default.
   2. Hover your mouse pointer over "Removable Devices" and then over the "CD/DVD" device option.
   3. Note: A tick next to the "CD/DVD" device will indicate that the device is connected to the virtual machine.
   4. Click on "Settings"
   5. Ensure that both the "Connected" check box is checked under the "Device Status" area
   6. Click the Radio Button entitled "Use ISO Image File" under the "Connection" area
   7. Click on the "browse...." button and navigate to the physical location of the ISO file on your host machine's hard drive.
   8. Note: Start with the first ISO file in the installation set.
   9. Click "OK" and now the ISO file should be presented to your virtual machine as a physical CD Rom media.
  10. Repeat the above steps for the other ISO files in the installation set when prompted by the operating system installer which is running inside of the virtual machine.
```

Point no 5 from above is what is missed.